# create service on android

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

I'm trying to create a service with rosjava on Android. However, I need to use an old rosjava version since I need the support for actionlib.

So, when I create the service server in my app, I can even see it with rxgraph on the linux machine running the roscore. However, as soon as i try to call the service via command line with "rosservice call /callme" (/callme is the name of the service) I receive following error messages:

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "/opt/ros/electric/ros/bin/rosservice", line 46, in <module> rosservice.rosservicemain() File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/tools/rosservice/src/rosservice.py", line 734, in rosservicemain _rosservice_cmd_call(argv) File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/tools/rosservice/src/rosservice.py", line 586, in _rosservice_cmd_call service_class = get_service_class_by_name(service_name) File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/tools/rosservice/src/rosservice.py", line 357, in get_service_class_by_name service_type = get_service_type(service_name) File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/tools/rosservice/src/rosservice.py", line 141, in get_service_type return get_service_headers(service_name, service_uri).get('type', None) File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/tools/rosservice/src/rosservice.py", line 113, in get_service_headers return roslib.network.read_ros_handshake_header(s, cStringIO.StringIO(), 2048) File "/opt/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/src/roslib/network.py", line 367, in read_ros_handshake_header raise ROSHandshakeException("connection from sender terminated before handshake header received. %s bytes were received. Please check sender for additional details."%b.tell()) roslib.network.ROSHandshakeException: connection from sender terminated before handshake header received. 0 bytes were received. Please check sender for additional details.`

The code is:
package com.example.sandbox_ros;

```
import org.ros.internal.node.service.ServiceException;
import org.ros.internal.node.service.ServiceResponseBuilder;
import org.ros.namespace.GraphName;
import org.ros.node.Node;
import org.ros.node.NodeMain;
import org.ros.service.myMessages.onlyReturn;

import android.util.Log;

public class TestServiceServer implements NodeMain {
    
    private final String TAG = "TestServiceServer";

    @Override
    public void onShutdown(Node arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onShutdownComplete(Node arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Node node) {
        
        /*ServiceServer<org.ros.message.std_msgs.Empty, org.ros.message.std_msgs.String> server = */
        node.newServiceServer("/callme", "myMessages/onlyReturn", new ServiceResponseBuilder<onlyReturn.Request, onlyReturn.Response>() {

            @Override
            public onlyReturn.Response build(onlyReturn.Request request) throws ServiceException {
                
                Log.i(TAG, "request: " + request.intput.data);
                
                onlyReturn.Response response = new onlyReturn.Response();
                response.output.data = "Thank you for calling! :)";
                
                Log.i(TAG, "I have been called!");

                return response;
            }
            
        });
    }

    @Override
    public GraphName getDefaultNodeName() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

and the node is created with:

```
NodeConfiguration configuration = NodeConfiguration.newPublic(androidhostIP, uriOfROSMachine);
Date date = new Date();
configuration.setNodeName("srs_ui_loc_start" + "_" + date.getTime());

TestServiceServer testNode = new TestServiceServer();

NodeMainExecutor runner = DefaultNodeMainExecutor.newDefault();

runner.execute(testNode, configuration);
```

I know, I'm using something old, but I though, maybe I'm not alone? :) Or maybe someone remembers that problem from former times?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47886/create-service-on-android/) by [markkre](https://answers.ros.org/users/1624/markkre/) on ROS Answers with karma: 77 on 2012-11-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [markkre](https://answers.ros.org/users/1624/markkre/) on 2012-11-15**:
funny thing: I have implemented the add_two_ints_server on Android. When I run "rosrun rospy_tutorials add_two_ints_client 1 2" it works, I receive "1 + 2 = 3" :D So, it seems to work with python clients. I think I can live with that workaround :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using a python ros service client instead of calling the server via "rosservice call /servicename parameters" command line works.

---

Originally posted by [markkre](https://answers.ros.org/users/1624/markkre/) with karma: 77 on 2012-11-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is an old bug that's fixed in newer versions of rosjava. I'm afraid you'll need to upgrade to get rid of it. The fix is non-trivial.

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-11-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [markkre](https://answers.ros.org/users/1624/markkre/) on 2012-11-15**:
an upgrade means, i can't use actionlib anymore. No option for me.